# What is the Smartest Way to Setup My Network Configuration?

Tags: networking, vpn, remote-connection, proxy-server

This is what I have:

1. Network
2. Remote VPN server

This is what I MUST do:

Route all the local network traffic to the remote VPN.

It's unfeasible to configure each client as there are many and they change often.

What is the smartest solution to this problem.

Thank you.

Comment: Put your VPN client on your gateway device.

Comment: Please extrapolate.

Comment: The "smartest"? That's quite a matter of opinion. By what measure do you consider a method "smart"?

Answer (score 1):

Have the [default route](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Default_route) on your network's router point to the VPN server.

Answer (score 1):

What Roland Smith is suggesting is correct, but it requires some extra explanation.

It is a nuisance to have to teach to all machines in your LAN how to contact the remote VPN server. It is much easier to place all configuration on a single machine, and let it take care of everything.

So basically what you want is a machine that acts both as a router to your LAN, and as a client to the remote VPN server. Acting as a client implies three distinct things:

1. Authenticating to the remote server;
2. Encrypting all data;
3. Forwarding all data.

Some routers can do that, others cannot. Those that can do that are those which use an Open Source software (like DD-WRT, OpenWRT, Tomato). You can buy one with this software already installed, or you can install it onto your existing router, if this allows such an operation. You can check which is the case by checking your router's model against the list of supported routers maintained in the Web pages of each of the afore-mentioned firmwares.

Alternatively, you can set up an old pc, if you have one, to act as a router, VPN client, and DHCP server to your LAN; this pc will then act as a go-between from your LAN to your true router and viceversa. On Google, you can find all sort of instructions on how to configure your pc to act as a router. It is more fun, but more demanding, than buying a router with DD-WRT pre-installed.